# Python - How to increment a file name within a definition?

Tags: python

I'm making a program where I need to save files with their names in order of creation, eg file_1, file_2, etc. I've done a lot of research on this and tried a few methods and none of them have worked for me. I'm fairly new to programming. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please post your latest effort, and explain what difficulties you are facing in your latest attempt.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create an `int` variable to hold your file ID.
2. Concatenate this `int` to the string `"file_"` when creating a new file.
3. Increment your `int` variable each time you create a file.

Something like this:

```
file_id = 0
open("file_" + str(file_id), "w+")
file_id += 1
open("file_" + str(file_id), "w+")
```

Another cleaner example with a `for` loop that would create 10 files:

```
for file_id in range(1, 10):
    open("file_" + str(file_id), "w+")
```

---

If you want to pick up where you left of when running a new instance of your program, you could save the `file_id` variable to a file and create a program that:

1. Reads `file_id` from your file
2. Creates a new file with this ID
3. Writes the next ID to the file

Here is an example, considering you have a file named `file_id.txt` that contains a number on its first line:

```
with open ("file_id.txt", "r") as file_id_txt:
    file_id = int(file_id_txt.readline())
open("file_" + str(file_id), "w+")
file_id += 1
with open ("file_id.txt", "w") as file_id_txt:
    file_id_txt.write(str(file_id))
```